# magnific ajax popup loading a dynamic html

Tags: jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

I am new to magnific popup. Forgive me if the question has an simple answer. But I have spent some time experimenting different ways and with no success.

I can use magnific popup to do inline and ajax with a static html but cannot get it to work with a dynamic html.

I want magnific popup to load a html with parameters such as http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test.html?activityid=22  test.html will show a title and a picture for that activityid. I can load the page with correct title and picture if I copy and paste that url into the browser. But magnific popup failed to load right title and picture and only load the default title and picture. It seems to me that information "activityid=22" is not passed. Do you know a good way to do it? Please help.

HTML:

```html
 <a class="simple-ajax-popup-align-top" href="test.html?activityid=22">open_popup</a>
```

Jquery:

```js
$('.simple-ajax-popup-align-top').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',
  alignTop: true,
  overflowY: 'scroll',
});
```

I have also tried to play with magnificPopup callbacks trying to set window.location.hash etc. but none worked. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What does your `simple-ajax-popup-align-top` HTML element look like?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to load a JSP page (same origin) using magnific popup, but it does not work.

In the javascript console I see that after loading the content using ajax, the plugin navigates to the JSP page. I see a popup window for a fraction of a second and then I see the new page.

**JS**

```js
$('.simple-ajax-popup-align-top').magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a',
  type: 'ajax',
  alignTop: true,
  overflowY: 'scroll',
  cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur',
  tError: '<a href="%url%">The content</a> could not be loaded.'
});
```

**home.jsp**

```html
<div class="simple-ajax-popup-align-top">
  <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/info">Load content via ajax</a>
</div>
```

**info.jsp (popup content)**

```html
<div id="custom-content" class="white-popup-block" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 20px auto;">
  ...my jsp content...
</div>
```

**JS Console**

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/test/info"

Navigated to http://localhost:8080/test/info
```